# Recommended IA and Navigation Architecture for a single long page scroll?

Tags: usability, navigation, user-behavior, information-architecture, user-centered-design

Website with several pages functioning as a long page scroll determining the optimal navigation architecture.  Are there any general usability suggestions for content rich websites with pages designed as a long page scroll? The current ux and proposed ux below. Is it generally recommended to keep main nav items or hide during scroll to focus user attention on landing page nav? I see different sites take different approaches. Current and Proposed UX below in jpeg format for illustration.

[image: Current UX]
[image: Prosed UX]

Answer (score 1):

You could try sticky section headers. Take a look at https://beta.thestar.com/

As you scroll, the title of the next section replaces the title in the page header.

Answer (score 0):

The general best practice for long pages is to keep customer engaged via a compelling story that one page is trying to tell. A combination of imagery and easy to read/ easy to follow copy.

**Menu:**

Hamburger icon is well understood on mobile devices and even expected, however the studies I've seen, all show that very little people notice/understand the hamburger icon on desktop experience.

**Header**

It is fairly common to convert the header to a simplified version of the header as the user scrolls down on lengthy pages and convert back to the full header as soon as the customer tries to scroll up.

Comment: Can you provide links or references to the studies you've seen re the hamburger icon?

Answer (score 0):

The word **Menu** which looks like a button (i.e. with an outline) seems to be the most user friendly.

Articles:
http://deep.design/the-hamburger-menu/
http://exisweb.net/mobile-menu-icons